# Laravel Array Validation Counts

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Within my Laravel application, I'm trying to validate that two of my arrays in my request add up to a specific number.

```
array1 => [1],
array2 => [],

'arary1' =>  ['bail', Rule::requiredIf(function () {
    return count($this->array2) <= 1;
})],
'array2' =>  ['bail', Rule::requiredIf(function () {
    return count($this->array1) <= 2;
})],
```

My total needed count for array1 and array 2 is 3. What is needed is to take the count of array1 and multiply that number by 2 and then add in the count array2.

So in the above example my validation should fail because (1*2) = 2 + 0 = 2 so does not equal 3.

How would this validation be constructed?

Comment: You can use `count()` function to calculate array counts and then check the sum. `count($array1)*2 + count($array2)` should be equal to 3 to pass the validation

Comment: How would that work with the Laravel framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need extend rule https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#using-extensions

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        Validator::extend('array_count', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
            $data = $validator->getData();
            $array1 = array_get($data, 'array1', []);
            $array2 = array_get($data, 'array2', []);
            return 3 == 2 * count($array1) + count($array2)
        });
    }
........
}
```

Usage

```
$rules = [
    'arary1' => 'array_count'
    ...............
];
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I have updated my post with existing validation rules.

Comment: @JeffreyDavidson In extebd rule I show how can get `$array1` and `$array2` values.